# Guide to the output of the apple airport -s command line utility

Tags: wifi, airport

The apple `airport --scan` command outputs something similar to the following...

```
macElCapitan: airport --scan
                SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)
        myhouse 5GHz 10:9a:dd:8c:xx:68 -48  100     Y  GB WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
             myhouse 10:9a:dd:8c:xx:67 -46  11      Y  GB WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
      TALKTALK12345A 10:d7:b0:8f:xx:xx -91  44      Y  GB WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
      TALKTALK12345A 10:d7:b0:8f:xx:xx -76  6       Y  -- WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
               guest bc:16:65:ba:xx:a1 -75  3       N  -- WPA2(PSK/TKIP/TKIP) 
             myhouse bc:16:65:ba:xx:a0 -77  3       N  -- WPA2(PSK/TKIP/TKIP)
```

Most of the column headers are obvious. But what does the 'HT' column stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here, `HT` stands for "**High Throughput**". It just shows is the network supports or not High Throughput (obviously, Y = yes and N = no).